# Xamarin ImageView перенос картинки из одного в другой по нажатию

Tags: изображения, xamarin

Xamarin ImageView перенос картинки из одного в другой Image, который сам создаётся

```
var button1 = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btnbacardi);
    button1.Click += imgV_Click;
```

Метод динамический

```
void imgV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
            FrameLayout FrameLayout1 =  FindViewById<FrameLayout>(Resource.Id.dropzone);
            ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
            image.SetImageResource();
            result.Text = ((ImageView)sender).Id.ToString ();;
            //FrameLayout1.AddView (image);
        }
```

Как мне достать картинку из ресурсов одного имаджа и копирнуть в другой?

Answer (score 2):

Не совсем понятно что ты хочешь.
Если фотография достается из ресурсов, то все просто:

```
image.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.img) // где img это фотка,загруженная в папку drawable
```

Можно получить сам ресурс как Drawable:

```
Drawable imgDrawable = imageView.Drawable; //imgDrawable будет содержать в себе ресурс от контрола ImageView
```

Так же можно вытащить ресурс ID из imageView(но это извращение):

```
int[] DrawableID = imageView.GetDrawableState(); //вернет массив ресурсов
```